# Elementary Dark Theme for Geany (GTK3)

Tags: themes, geany

Can anyone using 18.04 confirm that the Elementary Dark theme for Geany (the latest Geany release) works for 18.04 and not just for 16.04 ? Working example on 16.04 is demonstrated here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=In9tvv_ge9I

I followed the tutorial step by step on 18.04 but the geany interface just won't turn dark like it supposed to.

Comment: I don't see any Elementary Dark theme in the zip file I downloaded from https://github.com/geany/geany-themes. But all the dark themes in there work just fine.

Comment: this is the dark theme that turns the whole geany interface into gorgeous dark editor  https://www.deviantart.com/satya164/art/elementary-Dark-GTK3-Theme-244257862
it's a theme for Ubuntu-based os but the video demonstrates that the package can be used to beautify Geany editor.

Answer (score 2):

As turned out it actually worked. All I had to do is to launch Geany from `/usr/share/applications/geany.desktop` file for the theme to kick in.